# error: ‘n’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I wrote a function to find the sum of divisors for a number n.

```
int divisor_sum(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int a=1, a<=n, a++) {
        if n % a == 0 {
            sum = sum + a;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Unfortunately, the program (which includes a main function skeleton) won't compile because it says that "'n' was not declared in this scope." I've tried declaring n as a long before and after the function definition statement to no avail. How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: `if n % a == 0` --- > `if (n % a == 0)`. An if statement condition must be parenthesized in C++

Comment: The code really made me think it's Python or Perl...

Comment: `for (int a=1, a<=n, a++)` => `for (int a=1; a<=n; a++)` with semicolons.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

Like StoryTeller and O'Neil told you in the comments, you need to replace this

```
for (int a=1, a<=n, a++)
```

with

```
for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++)
```

and this

```
if n % a == 0
```

with

```
if (n % a == 0)
```